# Need help understanding RESTful apis in PHP

Tags: php, rest, curl

For a few weeks, I've been trying to gather as much information on implementation of RESTful apis in PHP as I can but in vain. All the information that is given online only explain the most basic concepts but never did I come across a very real example with complete code on how RESTapi actually works.

For Example, POST is used create a new resource. But how? How is it implemented in real life? How do I do this in cURL? I am aware of the complete basics but am unable to find any concrete and complete example that explains everything. Most of the tutorials simply name the functions they've used but did not bother explaining what is happening exactly, what the flow of the program is, etc.

If someone can help with a complete example (say, a library registration and database) I'll really appreciate it. I'm really confused.

Comment: There's no simple answer to this: a `PUT` or `POST` request is handled differently by most/all API's. It all depends on what they do. Generally, a RESTful API will process such a request by: 1) Validating the request data - authentication, check the request data for missing/invalid values etc... 2) Connect to data storage of choice (MySQL, NoSQL, or another service) 3) Data is stored successfully -> send a 200 response 3b) Data could not be stored: send an appropriate error response (400, 403, 500, ...)

Comment: So is it about generating the appropriate response?

Comment: The way you process the request is up to you. Whether or not an API is restful depends on how the API was implemented. Rest api's are: stateless, generally use HTTP GET, PUT, POST and DELETE requests, the client-server contract (server offers a clear contract through the API end-points, the it doesn't care what about what the client looks like)... Just read up on what RESTful actually means: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Answer (score 0):

I will describe POST method in REST.
Client send HTTP request via POST method with JSON data.

For example, client send some data to create a word "nice".

```
POST http://localhost/word/1
```

JSON content

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "word",
    "attributes": {
      "word": "nice"
    }
  }
}
```

In PHP you need get a response and convert to array and insert ot DB. Why insert? Because request method is POST.

Comment: But then why do we need REST? Why not simply use the action attribute of form and then insert the data in the DB? Why the need to do all this? One of the things I don't understand about REST.

Comment: @MithilBhoras Because REST API is standard for communicate over HTTP with HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.) between website (etc.) and remote server. REST API can use standard of response/request content like JSON API (http://jsonapi.org/).  For example you can use REST API for communicate between Android smartphones and your server.

Comment: @MithilBhoras: Because not only humans need to communicate with servers. Say I have a database of people in country X who don't have a gym membership, and a gym wants to compile a list of people living in a 10 mile radius, they don't want to hire a temp, but rather have somebody write a script in 30 minutes that does exactly that. People can do the same thing manually, only slower. API's exist for automation, and because automated data processing saves time and money